# Codeigniter can only access default route controller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I suspect this may be a webserver configuration change that has taken place, and my hosting provider hasn't told anyone, but anyway...

I have a Codeigniter instance set up with the following directory structure:

```
/root
   /codeigniter
        /app
        /sys
   /www
        /sandbox
            /ci
                /js
                /css
                /img
                .htaccess
                index.php
```

Therefore in index.php, I have the following variables:

```
$application_folder = '../../../codeigniter/app';
$system_path = '../../../codeigniter/sys';
```

These are relative definitions due to it being a shared hosting provider, however it does appear to be working that way so I don't think this is the issue (in WAMP i have those folder paths explicitly defined, e.g. c:/wamp/ci/application)

In config.php, I have the following variables set:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://******.co.uk/sandbox/ci/';
...
$config['index_page'] = '';
...
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and my .htaccess file in www/sandbox/ci is set like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Up until a few days ago, this all worked fine, however, I replaced a fair few files just before Christmas, and may have accidentally overwritten something without realising it.  This setup works fine on my WAMP server, but fails on my live server If I attempt to access any function in any controller that isn't the one defined in routes.php.

My routes.php looks like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home_controller";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

home_controller appears fine, however if I attempt to do something like login (which is processed via a form POST to auth_controller/login), it fails with 404.  I do not have any additional functions in home_controller.

I get nothing interesting from setting the logging threshold to 4, and ChromePHP just suggests that it cannot find a path to the controllers.

mod_rewrite seems to be working, because if I add anything plaintext to the .htaccess file, I get a server error 500, and furthermore the index.php rewrite is working.  I also have rewrite_short_tags set to TRUE.

I have tried all of the uri_protocol types in the config.php, and none seem to make any difference, so I feel like if it is something i've done, i'm either missing something from routes.php, or something missing from my .htaccess.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Like I said, this entire setup works on my WAMP server without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your htaccess. Try this htaccess for a moment..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Set the rewritebase to your CI installation folder
RewriteBase /sandbox/ci/


# Send everything to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: You, sir, are a god amongst men.  I remember fiddling around with the htaccess file a while ago, so I must have overwritten the rewritebase at some point and copied it back onto my hosting space.  Thankyou so much!

Comment: You're welcome! It's possible that WAMP is flexible with the RewriteBase but I'm not sure.. It's a long while ago I used WAMP. I hope it will come someday to mac :)

Comment: XAMPP is an alternative to WAMP for OS X.  As for RewriteBase, it could be that my WAMP instance was happy with it because index.php exists in a "default" location, i.e. (c:/wamp/www/index.php), whereas on my web server, it's 2 levels lower in directory structure (/var/www/sandbox/ci/index.php).  Either way, all is good with my world again :)